# airplane weight

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

I need some help for my homework.

On an airplane, 300 passengers will travel, whose weights are random and independent. The expectation of the total weight of all passengers is known to be 21000 kg. Every passenger is at least 10 kg heavy, and none of them can weigh more than 150 kg.
How much weight should the airplane be able to lift (counting passengers only), if we want to be $1-10^{-8}$ sure that the total weight of passengers doesn't exceed that?

How I start on this question? I have no idea on starting the question.

Comment: what is the probability distribution? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: I really have no idea on the probability distribution... It is not uniform distribution... since the mean is not 80*300 @JanDvorak

Comment: then the problem is ill-defined. I'm not entirely sure whether this is an answer or a close reason, but I think it's the latter.

Comment: I'm sure if this is homework, then either in your textbook or in class you will have seen a similar problem worked.  As Jan said, the essence of this problem is an *assumption* about the probability distribution.  As you note, a uniform distribution on [10kg,150kg] doesn't work because the mean would not give the right expectation of total weight.  However you must formulate an assumption of weight distribution in order to proceed with calculating a probability that the limit will be exceeded (or not).

Comment: how do you make use of the fact the individual weights must lie in the range [10,150]? @hardmath ?

Comment: While I suspect you've been given the approach to follow in the course's worked exercises, as I mentioned before, I'd otherwise be tempted to treat the population's weights as a binomial distribution, adjusting the probability $p$ of weight 10kg and probability $1-p$ of weight 150kg to get the *expected* total weight of 300 passengers to be 21000kg.  While not a realistic distribution, it should provide a conservative lift capacity $c$ when you go to calculate Pr( Total Passenger Weight $\le c$) > $1 - 10^{-8}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you aren't given the probability distribution, but *are* given that there is a well-defined expectation, there's only one option that remains (as far as I know):

> The [Central Limit Theorem](http://enwp.org/Central_limit_theorem).

Comment: Can we use the Markov inequality? since we know the expectation?

Comment: Yes, that'd also be an option. I guess my probability theory is a little rusty at times...

Comment: Ok, but how do you make use of the fact the individual weights must lie in the range [10,150]?

Comment: @freako This you'd do by suitably choosing the variance/standard deviation (so that the weights outside the specified interval are extremely unlikely).